# How to make a button panel, when mouse over, one button get larger, but the size change doesn't affect the layout of other buttons on the panel

Tags: css

[image]

Right now, when mouse over, the font get larger, but it stretch out the outer container.

I don't want the outer container to stretch out. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the margin down by the same amount that you are increasing the size of the element.

```
.button{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin:15px;
}
.button:hover{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tm1uethc/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing this solution and the demo!